# How do you edit checkout field labels in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, fieldsets, labels

The site I am working on is only selling to UK customers, and therefore we would like to change the labels from the Zip/Postal to Postcode and from State/Province to County.

I have spent a long time looking through the code with very little success, although I have also read online that it may be stored in the database somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

**You can overwrite below function for changing the Label at cart page in the file:**  vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/LayoutProcessor.php

```
public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        $elements = [
            'city' => [
                'visible' => $this->isCityActive(),
                'formElement' => 'input',
                'label' => __('City'),
                'value' =>  null
            ],
            'country_id' => [
                'visible' => true,
                'formElement' => 'select',
                'label' => __('Country'),
                'options' => [],
                'value' => null
            ],
            'region_id' => [
                'visible' => true,
                'formElement' => 'select',
                'label' => __('State/Province'),
                'options' => [],
                'value' => null
            ],
            'postcode' => [
                'visible' => true,
                'formElement' => 'input',
                'label' => __('Zip/Postal Code'),
                'value' => null
            ]
        ];

        if (!isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'] = [
                'country_id' => $this->countryCollection->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(),
                'region_id' => $this->regionCollection->addAllowedCountriesFilter()->toOptionArray(),
            ];
        }

        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']
            ['address-fieldsets']['children'])
        ) {
            $fieldSetPointer = &$jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']
            ['children']['address-fieldsets']['children'];
            $fieldSetPointer = $this->merger->merge($elements, 'checkoutProvider', 'shippingAddress', $fieldSetPointer);
            $fieldSetPointer['region_id']['config']['skipValidation'] = true;
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Translation for **State/Province** and **Zip/Postal Code** is found (by default) in **/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n** directory.

You can copy **locale's csv** file from **/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n** folder to **app/code/Magento/module-checkout/i18n** directory.

Then find the text and change its translation.

After saving file, don't forget to remove content from `/var/cache` folder and `/var/page_cache` folder.

Answer (score 0):

For 2.4 the labels can be change from DB eav_attribute table column frontend_label

Thanks