# Change labels on checkout page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, labels

On the checkout page I want to change the labels of Zip/Postal code and State/Province. I have updated the en_US.csv file, but nothing happens, despited clearing cache.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: you can check this reference: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126389/how-do-you-edit-checkout-field-labels-in-magento-2

Comment: You can explain more details how you added the translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**warn :** I am not sure this is  right way to done so cross check everything after update

```
SELECT `frontend_label` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `frontend_label` LIKE '%State/Province%' AND `frontend_input`='hidden'
SELECT `frontend_label` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `frontend_label` LIKE '%Zip/Postal Code%'
```

find the above field and change that **frontend_label** value as per your interest

for me it is working

[image]