# How to change checkout page field label in 2.1.7?

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

[image]

I want to change State/Province label. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

There are two to possible this.

**Way 1:**
      If you want to change the shipping address fields as well as billing address fields, you can do via theme transaction if you have made a custom theme as per your language.

*If you have a custom or third party theme:*

You might find a CSV file there. If you have kept locale as English(United States) which is a default one, there will be a file named en_US.csv

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\Themename\i18n
```

*Without theme:*

Copy locale's csv file from `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n` folder to `app/code/Magento/module-checkout/i18n` directory.

Exapmle:

```
"First Name","Volunteer First Name"
"Last Name","Volunteer Last Name"
```

**Way 2:**
      If you change made in shipping address fields only, Please override LayoutProcessor.php

**Step 1** *di.xml*

> path: app/code/vendor/module_name/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="Custom_Checkout" type="vendor\Module\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

Step 2:
*LayoutProcessor.php*

> path:app/code/vendor/module_name/Block/

```
         public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['lastname']['label'] = __('Recipient lastname'); 

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['region_id']['label'] = __('Division'); 

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

**It's work like charm**

Answer (score 0):

According to this topic [How do you edit checkout field labels in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126389/how-do-you-edit-checkout-field-labels-in-magento-2) (sorry, wouldn't let me post as comment)

> Translation for State/Province and Zip/Postal Code is found (by
>   default) in /vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n directory.
>
> You can copy locale's csv file from
>   /vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n folder to
>   app/code/Magento/module-checkout/i18n directory.
>
> Then find the text and change its translation.
>
> After saving file, don't forget to remove content from /var/cache
>   folder and /var/page_cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

**You can overwrite below function for changing the Label at cart page in the file:**  vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/LayoutProcessor.php

```
public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        $elements = [
            'city' => [
                'visible' => $this->isCityActive(),
                'formElement' => 'input',
                'label' => __('City'),
                'value' =>  null
            ],
            'country_id' => [
                'visible' => true,
                'formElement' => 'select',
                'label' => __('Country'),
                'options' => [],
                'value' => null
            ],
            'region_id' => [
                'visible' => true,
                'formElement' => 'select',
                'label' => __('State/Province'),
                'options' => [],
                'value' => null
            ],
            'postcode' => [
                'visible' => true,
                'formElement' => 'input',
                'label' => __('Zip/Postal Code'),
                'value' => null
            ]
        ];

        if (!isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'] = [
                'country_id' => $this->countryCollection->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(),
                'region_id' => $this->regionCollection->addAllowedCountriesFilter()->toOptionArray(),
            ];
        }

        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']
            ['address-fieldsets']['children'])
        ) {
            $fieldSetPointer = &$jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']
            ['children']['address-fieldsets']['children'];
            $fieldSetPointer = $this->merger->merge($elements, 'checkoutProvider', 'shippingAddress', $fieldSetPointer);
            $fieldSetPointer['region_id']['config']['skipValidation'] = true;
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
```