# Change label of State/Province in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, labels

I want to change the label of State/Province to just State only in the checkout field in magento 2. I am trying to update it via i18n and insert it in my custom module. But the label is not updated.
[image]

Comment: please check this thread, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180680/how-to-change-checkout-page-field-label-in-2-1-7

Comment: OK, this reference works for me thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link would be helpful for changing labels in shipping fields in the checkout.

> [How to change checkout page field label in 2.1.7?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180680/how-to-change-checkout-page-field-label-in-2-1-7)

I have added the labels in i18n's en_US CSV and that has done my job.

Thanks, @Mujahidh for the link

Answer (score 0):

Can do it using `AttributeMerger`'s **afterMerge** function.
Create a basic custom module and add the following file to your module.

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger">
    <plugin name="checkoutFieldLableChange" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\AttributeMergerPlugin"/>
</type>
```

Next create the **AttributeMergerPlugin.php** file in the following location `Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\AttributeMergerPlugin.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;
class AttributeMergerPlugin
{
public function afterMerge(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger $subject, $result)
{
    if (array_key_exists('city', $result)) {
        $result['city']['label'] = 'Your Label';
    }
    if (array_key_exists('region_id', $result)) {
        $result['region_id']['label'] = 'Your Label';
    }

    return $result;
}
}
```