# How can I change phone number label to Mobile number in Checkout Page;Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I need to change Phone number label into Mobile number label which is  present under Shipping address in Checkout Page.Please suggest me how to do it.Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/126394)

Comment: @Hit's I tried this.But it doesn't work.So only I asked here.

Comment: @ManashviBirla.The link you have provided does not include Phone number.Thats why I have asked separately.

Comment: @VishaliMariappan which Magento version are you used? as I just tried in Magento 2.2.6 and I translate successfully

Comment: @Hit's.I am using Magento2.2.4.Just one clarification.In code folder, I have Magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv.Is it module-checkout or Module_Checkout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1**.Create di.xml under app/code/Namespace/Module/etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="rewrite-checkout-fields" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**2**.Create LayoutProcessorPlugin.php under app/code/Namespace/Module/Model/Checkout.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['telephone']['label'] = __('Mobile Number'); 

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

**See screen shot** : [image]
Please try the above code if useful then accept it will help others too.