# What is the best way change the label of fields in Shipping Address during checkout?

Tags: shipping-address, magento2.2.6

In **Magento 2.2.6** Checkout where **First Name**, **Last Name** and **Street Address** is prompted.

I wanted them to displayed as `Volunteer First Name`, `Volunteer Last Name` and `Centre Address`. What is the best to way to change the label of the Address Field.

In short:

```
First Name -> Volunteer First Name
Last Name -> Volunteer Last Name
Street Address -> Centre Address
```

Answer (score 4):

To change the label for `First Name` to `Volunteer First Name` , `Last Name` and `Street Address`.

Copy locale's csv file from `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n` folder to `app/code/Magento/module-checkout/i18n` directory.

And Add:

```
"First Name","Volunteer First Name"
"Last Name","Volunteer Last Name"
"Street Address","Volunteer Street Address"
```

> After saving file, don't forget to remove content from `/var/cache`
>   folder and `/var/page_cache` folder.

**Reference** : [How do you edit checkout field labels in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/126389/3368)